# Создание бота для записи на приём

Tags: бот

Задача создать программу или бота для отслеживания появления мест и записи на приём. Т.е. заходить на сайт заполнять форму, проходить капчу и проверять не появились ли места. При появлении мест записываться на приём.
Так же, чтобы бот в телеграмме присылал оповещение об появлении мест.
На сколько сложно это реализовать технически? Как это делается? Сколько это может стоить?

Comment: Ваш вопрос некорректно составлен и не понятно чего вы хотите, если всё понимать так как можно понять исходя из того что я прочитал:
1-Сложность зависит от понимания вами этой темы, 2-Для начала можно начать с изучения telebot, 3-Ровно столько, сколько за это потребует фрилансер. Или вы здесь чтоб за вас всё написали и бесплатно отдали вам исходники многочасовой работы?

Comment: Я в этой теме полный ноль. Для понимания хочу разобраться хотя бы поверхностно сколько это может занять времени, на сколько технически это сложно реализовать. Так как одни фрилансеры говорят, что сделают это за 150тр, а другие за 20тр. Бесплатно я ничего не прошу. И  соответственно, чтобы хотя бы приблизительно понимать сколько это может стоить.

Comment: касаемо стоимости ничем помочь не могу, если вы оказались здесь то думаю вы так же заинтересованы в реализации этого своими силами, в таком случае могу порекомендовать изучить крайне удобный хоть и медленный python и его библиотеку telebot.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.